# How to Add Child in ExpandableListview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How are you?

I need your help, I am trying do a ExpandableListview with information of WS, I get first info Group, when I make Click in an Item of Group, I must get the Information of the other Web Services and show, my Questions is How i refresh the Child list and expand the information dynamicallt?. If i create and showed the ExpandableList before only with GroupHeader.

Thanks for your attention, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to update your `ListAdapter` with the new group/children information. Assuming you already had some `ExpandableListAdapter` generated, you could create a new one, and then update the adapter for the ListView when the new data is available:

```
private ExpandableListView mList;
private SimpleExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    // assume you've already set up the data in the adapter as per the description

    mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            //... all of the fields to initialize, passing in the new children info ...
            );
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```